# Does AngularJS $templateCache store data on local hardrive

Tags: angularjs, caching

I'm building an application that presents sensitive patient information.
One of my routes shows presents an HTML fragment received from the server that contains an image of a patient document.

**I need to ensure that that document is not accessible on disk after the page is closed**
That would be a really big issue if it was left there.

I noticed that the route was caching and I had to remove it from $templateCache to detect changes. Is that just cached in memory or is it local hdd?

A broader question might be: does Angular cache anything on persistent storage beyond what the browser already does according to HTTP cache control headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on the abstraction level you look at:

A Javascript app cannot write arbitrary files to the disk - there is the well-known browser sandbox, and this also applies to angular.js apps. So, if you are not specifically using the Browser offline APIs such as LocalStorage, Cookies, ... in your own code, there will be "just" the usual browser cache. So you should be fine.

Caveat 1: Sometimes it seems to be quite hard to control the browser caches, there are multiple ways browsers cache things as you already mentioned. They can usually be by http headers. So if you configure your HTTP headers very carefully you should be fine.

Caveat 2: There are multiple ways operating systems cache things and they may or may not save some of these caches to disk (as a simple example consider the windows hibernation file: there is probably a copy of your image in there when you had it open in your browser upon hibernation.). This cannot be controlled by a browser app - but for most applications it does not really matter.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was expecting but this gives me the warm fuzzy feeling that I'm not doing something in ignorance.